# Masm32 set colors of rich text edit

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I am new to assembly and i am trying to create a simple text editor in masm32 on windows. Editor works, but i am struggeling in setting the background color and text color.
I know one can do it with EM_[SETCHARFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcharformat). In c it would look like as follows:

```
void setTextColor( HWND richEditCtrl, COLORREF textColor, COLORREF bgColor)
{
  CHARFORMAT2 cf ;

  cf.cbSize = sizeof( CHARFORMAT2 ) ;
  cf.dwMask = CFM_COLOR | CFM_BACKCOLOR ; // Only set the text and background color
  cf.crTextColor = textColor ;
  cf.crBackColor = bgColor ;

  SendMessage( richEditCtrl, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_ALL, (LPARAM)&cf ) ;
}
```

In Masm32 i have the following code (parts marked with *???* are the ones i am struggleing with)

```
setTextColor proc edit:DWORD, txtColor:DWORD, bgColor:DWORD
  ; Color must be of format: <AABBGGRR>
  LOCAL charfmt:CHARFORMAT2

  movi charfmt.cbSize, sizeof CHARFORMAT2 ;???
  mrm charfmt.dwMask, CFM_COLOR or CFM_BACKCOLOR
  mrm charfmt.crTextColor, txtColor
  mrm charfmt.crBackColor, bgColor

  invoke SendMessage, hEdit, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_ALL, ADDR charfmt ;???

  ret
setTextColor endp
```

I already have a function to set the background color, which is fairly easy:

```
set_bgc proc edit:DWORD, color:DWORD
  invoke SendMessage,edit,EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR,0,color

  ret
set_bgc endp
```

Unfortuately there is no simple message like *EM_SETFRGNDCOLOR* like you have for the background color *EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR*.

I dont know how to set up the lparams struct in masm and how to get the size of the CHARFORMAT2 struct.

The errors i get are:

```
error A2008: syntax error : integer
error A2012: PROC, MACRO, or macro repeat directive must 
precede LOCAL
error A2008: syntax error : charfmt
error A2006: undefined symbol : charfmt
error A2114: INVOKE argument type mismatch : argument : 4
```

[EDIT]

Somehow removing the last parameter of the function works. This was causing the chain of errors.

```
set_fgc proc edit:DWORD, txtColor:DWORD ; , bgColor:DWORD
  ; Color must be of format: <AABBGGRR>
  LOCAL charfmt  :CHARFORMAT2

  mov charfmt.cbSize, sizeof CHARFORMAT2
  mrm charfmt.dwMask, CFM_COLOR
  mrm charfmt.crTextColor, txtColor
  mrm charfmt.crBackColor, bgColor

  invoke SendMessage, edit, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_ALL, ADDR charfmt

  ret
set_fgc endp
```

Does someone know why this is?

Comment: Why is this tagged [nasm] and [fasm] if you're using [masm32]?

Comment: When it comes to your questions: masm32 has a `SIZEOF` operator, so `SIZEOF CHARFORMAT2` ought to twork. It's not clear what your question regarding `ADDR` is.

Comment: The error sais it is an argument type mismatch. (I removed the [nasm][fasm] tags.

Comment: What are `movi` and `mrm` supposed to be? Please post a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce the errors you describe.

Comment: movi was wrong it must be mov. mrm is because i cant mov from memlocation to memlocation. The main problem though was the last parameter bgColor:DWORD. Removed it and it works. As im new, can someone explain why this is? The last parameter caused the chain of errors like charfmt unkown symbol etc.. Ive edited the post and added the solution.